# MongoDB - different structure for error "cannot index parallel arrays"

Tags: mongodb

i have the following document structure:

```
{
  "_id": "123",
  "timestamp": 1628632419,
  "propertyA": "A",
  "propertyB": "B",
  "propertyC": "C",
  "propertyD": "D",
  "propertyE": "E",
  "myArray": [
    {
      "myNestedArray": [
        {
          "name": "NestedName1",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "name": "NestedName2",
          "value": "2"
        },
        {
          "name": "NestedName3",
          "value": "3"
        }
      ],
      "type": "MyType",
      "name": "MyName",
      "nestedPropertyA": "A",
      "nestedPropertyB": "B",
      "nestedPropertyC": "C",
      "nestedPropertyD": "D",
      "nestedPropertyE": "E",
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

With that, I want to create an index like that:

```
collection.createIndex({
        'myArray.type': 1,
        'myArray.myNestedArray.name': 1,
        'myArray.myNestedArray.value': 1,
    })
```

This results in:

> **cannot index parallel arrays**

I read through mongoDB's [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/core/index-multikey/index.html?_ga=2.152523964.425476867.1658823144-38703468.1656513560&_gac=1.156758473.1657524850.Cj0KCQjwlK-WBhDjARIsAO2sErTq674EFmosvhRxSpuUTUGdzgCPpsrxanl7TGU-510hqs2FpUGMuUIaAhBLEALw_wcB#limitations) and I understand where the problem is. Now my question is, what is a good structure for my document, in order that my indexing is working?

I found the approach to structure from:

```
{a:[1,2], b:[8,9]}
```

to:

```
{ab:[[1,8], [1,9], [2,8], [2,9]]}
```

But as I see this approach for my situation, the objects under `myArray` are too complex.

I was also thinking about moving the array indices as own properties like:

```
"type": "MyType",
"name": "MyName",
"myNestedArray0": {
  "name": "NestedName1",
  "value": "1"
},
"myNestedArray1": {
  "name": "NestedName2",
  "value": "1"
},
...
```

But this feels wrong and is also not really flexible, furthermore the indexing would be a fix number like:

```
collection.createIndex({
        'myArray.type': 1,
        'myArray.myNestedArray0.name': 1,
        'myArray.myNestedArray0.value': 1,
        'myArray.myNestedArray1.name': 1,
        'myArray.myNestedArray1.value': 1,
         ...
    })
```

Another thought would be, refactoring the `myNestedArray` to an independent collection. My problem here is, that I need the properties like "propertyA", "propertyB" etc. Furthermore, the `myNestedArray` could have many entries, so it could multiply the amount of documents immensive.

Can someone give me an advice how to proceed here.

Comment: Are you sure you need the array of arrays structure?  Besides `timestamp` is there anything else common to the inner `myNestedArray`?    What would happen if you exploded `myArray` out into multiple documents?

Comment: Hi @BuzzMoschetti,
I made a small edit on my post. So basically, I have more properties like timestamp, but i'm also more and more convinced, that I have to extract the myNestedArray to multiple documents

Comment: I just tried this on a version 4.4.3 and was able to create the 3 part index without error.  When I call
`db.foo.find({'myArray.type':'ZZZ','myArray.myNestedArray.name':'NestedName1'}).explain(true)`
The query plan says it will use the index (IXSCAN) on index `"indexName" : "myArray.type_1_myArray.myNestedArray.name_1_myArray.myNestedArray.value_1"`

Weird...

Comment: With 3 part index you mean this: 'myArray.myNestedArray.name': 1. Cause this is also working for me. The problem is indexing myArray and myNestedArray like so:
{
        'myArray.type': 1,
        'myArray.myNestedArray.name': 1,
}

Comment: No I mean:  `createIndex({'myArray.type': 1,
        'myArray.myNestedArray.name': 1,
        'myArray.myNestedArray.value': 1,
});`
The `explain()` fragment in my last comment confirms that a `find()` is using this 3 component key.